# PrincipalPermission with Role= "" always fails

Tags: c#, .net, forms-authentication, authorization, declarative-authorization

I'm using forms authentication on my asp.net 3.5 webforms app.
I have a custom class implementing `IIdentity`.
I've decorated my method with `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "administration")]`.
My problem is that even when i'm logged on as a user that's in that role, I get a security exception. This has happened with every combination of role / user I've tried.
however, if I use `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "admin")]` the authorization works as expected.
I'm sure that my `GetRoles()` method returns the correct roles strings.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?